# HTML5 Audio Play/Get Request - Count - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, http

I am currently trying to count the amount of listens a particular song has.

In my rails app, a song has_many listens. I'll use an increment counter to update the count and think I have a good understanding of counter cache as well.

My problem comes in when understanding what exactly to count or track. I'm using HTML5's new audio with js.

Seeing that a user wants to play a song and makes a GET request to play the song, how do I count the number of GET requests made? Or should I even be trying to count the requests?

The song is uploaded via paperclip

request is made here :

```
<%= link_to 'Play Song', song_upload.song.url, :class => "html5" %>
```

and is played here :

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var audioSection = $('section#audio');  
$('a.html5').click(function() {  

    var audio = $('<audio>', {  
         controls : 'controls'  
    });  

    var url = $(this).attr('href');  
    $('<source>').attr('src', url).appendTo(audio);  
    audioSection.html(audio);  
    return false;  
});
```

});

Essentially, a user clicks the 'play song' button and the song is played through the player directly above. Hope this is enough code.

Comment: Need to post some of your code, i.e. how you're requesting the song

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated @varatis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you should have a model for Listens, unless you need to keep track of who listened to what. It could easily just be a field otherwise. I'll write this as a field, but you can easily adapt it to suit your needs. I'm just unsure of what fields a Listen would have.

Inside of the click(), add some AJAX to send info to your controller. For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/increment.json',
    data: { "song_id" : "<%= @song.id %>"},
    async: false
});
```

Of course you'll have to add a route for this as well.

```
match "increment.json" => "songs#increment"
```

And finally, respond to the call in your Songs controller.

```
def increment
  Song.find_by_id(params[:id]).listens += 1
end
```